# how to compress entire debian distro into an iso backup to flash raspberry pi sd card later?

Tags: debian, raspberry-pi, iso-image, sd-card, raspbian

i specifically want to do this as i used berryboot to install a version of raspbian without a gui as i was going to be using it without a monitor for nonstop daily use. the problem for me is that berryboot makes boot times very long and has a few compatibility issues from what i've seen. my question is, is there a way to compress the entire installation into an iso so that i can wipe my sd card and flash it after so that berryboot is gone but my raspbian installation remains? thanks.

Comment: I recommend using accurate terms. ISO images are specifically for optical media. You just want a raw image or perhaps a TAR archive of the root filesystem.

Comment: If you're using any regular PC there are many ways and many software tools for that.

Comment: @DanielB then what's with all the usage of isos for ubuntu? i don't believe the majority of computers come equipped with those nowadays. either way, that sounds like something i could use.

Comment: They are ISOHybrid images, an entirely different beast. Still ISO images, yet also MBR-partitioned.